# How to append String from an array to Text() in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have strings in an array. I need to append all the elements of the array based on the index to the `Text()` in mapreduce. I need to append the values as string in the Text()

For example:

```
 String s = "12,23";
 String[] array = s.split(",");
 Text t1 = new Text();
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
     t1.append(array[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method: `append(byte[] utf8, int start, int len)` ([Javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#append(byte[],%20int,%20int)))

So your code would look something like:

```
t1.append(array[i].getBytes(), 0, array[i].getBytes().length);
```

As a quick unit test:

```
@Test
public void textAppendTest() {

    String s = "12,23";
    String[] array = s.split(",");
    Text t1 = new Text();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        t1.append(array[i].getBytes(), 0, array[i].getBytes().length);
    }
    System.out.println(t1); // prints 1223
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well ..I replaced start with 0 . Its not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way without need of an array of splited strings:

```
String str = "12,23";
String newStr = str.replace("," , ""); // or replace with any character or string you want between those numbers
Text text = new Text(newStr);
```

Comment: I dont want to do in this method, i have to access based on the index